# GWT add a widget above the existing widget

Tags: java, gwt

I have a `VericalPanel`. If I add an element to it, it will be added under the element, now how can I place an Element over it?

```
VerticapPanel vpanel  = new VerticalPanel()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
VerticalPanel#insert(Widget w, int beforeIndex)
```

instead of

```
VerticalPanel#add(Widget w)
```

This will insert the widget at the given position.

Comment: i found it in the same moment LOL ty anyways

Answer (score 2):

Try the `insert` method:

Here the description of the method regarding the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ComplexPanel.html#insert(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element,%20int,%20boolean))

> `protected void insert(Widget child,
>             Element container,
>             int beforeIndex,
>             boolean domInsert)`
>
> Insert a new child Widget into this Panel at a specified index, attaching its Element to the specified
>   container Element. The child Element will either be attached to the
>   container at the same index, or simply appended to the container,
>   depending on the value of domInsert.
>
> Parameters:
>   `child` - the child Widget to be added
>   `container` - the Element within which child will be contained
>   `beforeIndex` - the index before which child will be inserted
>   `domInsert` - if `true`, insert child into container at `beforeIndex`; otherwise append child to the end of container.